# Autofac: Registering nested generic Interfaces and classes

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, autofac

I have a DI Autofac in my WebApi project. Autofac cannot resolve. I would like to achieve a situation when I can create new interfaces that implement `IDB to provide new subclass that overrides some methods. I also want to replace DPB with some inherited class in the future.

Here is the code structure:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/ro")]
public class RODController : ApiController
{
    public RODController(IFO fO, IROD<IDPB> rOD)
    {
        _fO = fO ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(fO));
        _rOD = rOD ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(rOD));
    }
}

public interface IROD<T> : IDB<T> where T : IDPB
{ }

public class ROD<T> : DB<T>, IROD<IDPB> where T : IDP
{
    public ROD(IFO fO, T dPB) : base(fO, dPB)
    { }
}

public interface IDB<T> : IDF where T : IDPB
{ }

public abstract class DB<T> : IDB<T> where T : IDPB
{
    protected DB(IFO fO, T dPB)
    {
        _fO = fO ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(fO));
        _dPB = dPB;
    }
}

public interface IDPB
{ }

public class DPB : IDPB
{ }
```

public IDF - provide only method to implement by IDB

I have tried code below but with no success

```
builder.RegisterType<FO>().As<IFO>().InstancePerRequest();
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(ROD<>))
    .As(typeof(IROD<>)).InstancePerDependency;
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(DB<>))
    .As(typeof(ID<>)).InstancePerDependency();
builder.RegisterType<DPB>().As<IDPB>().InstancePerDependency();

builder.RegisterType<ROD<DPB>>()
    .As<IROD<IDPB>>();

builder.RegisterType<DPB>().As<IDPB>();
```

The following error is attached below.

> None of the constructors found with
>   'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type
>   'ROD`1[DPB]' can be invoked with the available services and
>   parameters:
>       Cannot resolve parameter 'DPB dPB' of constructor 'Void .ctor(IFO, DPB)'.

I wonder because these mappings worked in Unity (ported project).

**Edit 1**

If I understand you correctly, my answer is yes.
I would like to resolve any `ROD<T>` service of that that implement `IDPB`. Like in this scenario `ROD<T>` should be resolved by DPB coming from `builder.RegisterType<ROD<DPB>>().As<IROD<IDPB>>();`

`IROD<IDPB>` is a simple way to resolve any dependent class from `IDB<T>` by different interface name (differentiate from resolving by name).

I simples way in which I can explain my need is to resolve

```
builder.RegisterType<ROD<DPB>>().As<IROD<IDPB>>();
```

In `Unity <package id="Unity" version="4.0.1" targetFramework="net461" />` a few years late I wrote this that work with this abstract classes.

```
container.RegisterType<IROD<IDPB>, ROD<DPB>>()
```

**Edit 2**

I created a project on github at https://github.com/fruex/StackOverflowAutofac, it generates the same error as described above.

I also prepared a test that directly generates an error (https://github.com/fruex/StackOverflowAutofac/blob/master/StackOverflowAutofacTest/RODControllerTests.cs).
The URL for this controller is host:port/api/ro/convert

**Edit 3**

I've added builder.RegisterType(); and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception states that Autofac looks for a type named `DPB` in the constructor of `ROD<T>`, but there is no registration for `DPB`. There is, however, a registration for `IDPB` that *maps* to `DPB`. Did you meant to let `ROD<T>` depend on `IDPB` instead?

Comment: That' why Stack Overflow asks you to build a MCVE. It's not only for us to understand, but for yourself as well. Your new solution is this MCVE.

Comment: I think I was in a premature euphoria. During the changes, I removed the inheritance from this class. I created a project on github at https://github.com/fruex/StackOverflowAutofac, it generates the same error as described above.

I also prepared a test that directly generates an error (https://github.com/fruex/StackOverflowAutofac/blob/master/StackOverflowAutofacTest/RODControllerTests.cs).
The URL for this controller is host:port/api/ro/convert